# How's maturation different from differentiation/activation of B lymphocyte?

Tags: homework, immunology

I was reading Wikipedia that said $-$

> In mammals, B cells mature in the bone marrow, which is at the core of most bones. In birds, B cells mature in the **B**ursa of Fabricius, a lymphoid organ.

So it's got the name **B**-lymphocyte.

**My questions**:

Is the transformation of Haemotopoetic stem cell to Immature B-cell called ***maturation of B-lymphocyte*** and the transformation of Immature B-cell to Mature B-cell through a Naive B-cell called ***differentiation/activation of B-lymphocyte***?

The maturation occurs in Bone-marrow and Activation/differentiation in Spleen or lymph nodes. The whole process maturatiion + activation is called development. ***Am I correct?***

Note: My understanding of Immature B-cell is that it is a cell in the series of B-cell development that expresses BCR (an IgM) for the first time. While Mature B cell is a B lymphocyte which after interaction with antigen has turned into either Plasma cell or Memory cell.

Comment: yup. activation is when a naive b-cell binds an antigen generally in the secondaries. maturation is in the primaries..

Comment: Initially I thought it should be the opposite. You see Immature transforming into Mature B-cell, common sense says it should be maturation but it just the opposite. Well what is differentiation and development then? @Polisetty

Comment: @Polisetty Do you mind sparing your time explaining some very confusing immunological concepts to me.? They are Isotype, Allotype and Idiotype.

Comment: Why not ask a question? Ill try answering it